# Will retry_on_conflict query parameter in Elastic search produces data loss?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a scenario where multiple requests are hitting the ES server concurrently resulting in 409 version conflict. So I followed the official documentation of ES and started using the retry_on_conflict query parameter in the header.

What are the side effects of using the param?
Will there be any data loss by using the query param?
Will both the documents get merged ?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Official documentation:
retry_on_conflict
(Optional, integer) Specify how many times should the operation be retried when a conflict occurs. Default: 0.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html

Comment: So you are trying to update the same document from different processes? What are the updates about? Should all go through or are they redundant somehow? Please explain your use case in more details.

Comment: Updating the same document from different processes. Lets say two persons are modifying the document concurrently 
1st person Modifies name -> xyz
2nd person modifies salary -> 1000 
Will both these attributes get indexed during conflict

Comment: @Val will both the updates be present after the retry

Comment: If there are only two concurrent processes, it makes sense to increase `retry_on_conflict` to at least 1, i.e. the first time it might fail because the other process took precedence, but the second time it will work because the other process is done and how the second process can proceed.

Comment: will this result in data loss ? Will it merge both these documents

Comment: There is only one document, not two. But the first update will succeed and then the second as well, provided the updates can be retried in case of conflicts, that's the whole point

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241202/discussion-between-sudarshan-and-val).